# Wso2 file upload. connection reset

Tags: web-services, rest, tomcat, soap, wso2

I developed a SOAP Web Service and Client for file upload (a base64binary string that i want to write on my database) and everithing works fine. I wrote REST api interface with Wso2 ESB and a Rest Client to use my SOAP services with the JSON to XML conversion provided by Wso2 and i succeeded in most of cases.
The problem occurs when i try to upload a base64binary String, obtained from a file grater than 16385 byte (with smaller files works fine) through REST API interface.
After few seconds the connection is reset by the server (Wso2 i think, since my application server doesn't gets the request) and no error is shown other than connection timeout.
I use Apache cxf2 for web service and client generation, Tomcat 8 as apllication server and Wso2 ESB to comunicate with Tomcat.

Here is my Socket Exception in Rest Client

```
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at rest.RestClient.main(RestClient.java:190)
```

and the Rest API interface with some censure:

```
    <resource methods="POST"
         protocol="https"
         uri-template="/loadDoc?user={user}&amp;pwd={pwd}">
  <inSequence>
     <header name="Action" value="loadDoc"/>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <m0:loadDoc xmlns:m0="my service location">
              <username xmlns="">$1</username><password xmlns="">$2</password>$3
           </m0:loadDoc>
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.user')"/>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.pwd')"/>
           <arg evaluator="json" expression="$."/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="my wsdl location uri"
                    format="soap12"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 ESB has a default size of the buffer through which data passes.
This default is 16384 bytes.

Go to WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/**passthru-http.properties** and adjust **io_buffer_size** property as you need.